# Как увеличить четные числа массива на второй аргумент?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Если аргумент массив то нужно увеличить четные числа на delta и вернуть результирующий массив`

```js
const increaseEvenEl = (arr, delta) => {
  if(!Array.isArray(arr)){
    return null
  }

  let result = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] % 2 === 0){
      result = arr[i] + delta;
    }
  }
  return result;
};

// examples
console.log(increaseEvenEl([2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 9, 4], 20)); // ===> [22, 5, 26, 28, 11, 9, 24]
console.log(increaseEvenEl([7, 11, 1], 10)); // ===> [7, 11, 1]
console.log(increaseEvenEl([], 120)); // ===> []
```

`

Comment: Зачем ставить столько меток, даже не понимая что они значат?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const increaseEvenEl = (arr, delta) => {
  if(!Array.isArray(arr)){
    return null
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] % 2 === 0){
      arr[i] = arr[i] + delta;
    }
  }
  
  return arr;
};

// examples
console.log(increaseEvenEl([2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 9, 4], 20)); // ===> [22, 5, 26, 28, 11, 9, 24]
console.log(increaseEvenEl([7, 11, 1], 10)); // ===> [7, 11, 1]
console.log(increaseEvenEl([], 120)); // ===> []
```

Comment: спасибо) а подскажите почему result не подходит? Можете объяснить почему такое решение?

Comment: result подходит, если его формировать корректно..... например на каждой итерации складывать (делать push в **массив** result) в него значение из arr и если чётное - то складывать (делать **push** ) увеличенное на дельту......ты же этого не делала..... ты просто в переменную заносила на каждой итерации новое другое значение.........

Comment: а как через push можно записать?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 1):

Простой и однострочный вариант без мутации оригинального массива:

```js
const increaseEvenEl = (arr, delta) => Array.isArray(arr) ? arr.map(x => x % 2 === 0 ? x + delta : x) : null;

// examples
console.log(increaseEvenEl([2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 9, 4], 20)); // ===> [22, 5, 26, 28, 11, 9, 24]
console.log(increaseEvenEl([7, 11, 1], 10)); // ===> [7, 11, 1]
console.log(increaseEvenEl([], 120)); // ===> []
console.log(increaseEvenEl(5, 120)); // ===> null
console.log(increaseEvenEl({map:(x) => console.log(x(2))}, 120)); // ===> null
```

Comment: Кто-то не любит условный оператор...

Comment: @Qwertiy Только из-за этого комментария я убрал логические операторы и оставил только тернарные :)

Comment: Кстати в моём случае даже нет мутации изначального массива :)

Comment: ну про мутацию автору виднее, что ему надо.

Comment: @Qwertiy нужно без, в другом вопросе спросил про это :)